# Jackrabbit permissions for multiple principals

Tags: jcr, jackrabbit

I'm developing custom security scheme for web application based on Apache Jackrabbit. I've extended standard Jackrabbit security implementation for my needs, and so far it's working correctly. But, I'm having problems with multiple principals being assigned permissions on a node.

For example, user U is a member of group G. Groups G has no read permissions on a node, but user U has read permissions. What I mean by this is, group G has `jcr:read` privilege set to `deny`, and user U has `jcr:read` set to `allow` on a node.

Based on this, I would assume that user U would be able to read the node, even if he is a member of a group which is not allowed to read. However, the node does not show up for a user U (not expected), or for any other member of group G (expected).

Could somebody help me shed some light on this? Is my assumption correct, or does Jackrabbit calculate actual permissions differently? Or is this just an error in my security implementation?

Comment: You can also use  `Privilege[] AccessControlManager.getPrivileges(String absPath)` to get all privillés for the current session on the node

Comment: Try to download the JCR spec http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/content_repository-2.0-pfd-oth-JSpec . and be sure you read it if you work on JackRabbit. The Access Control Management is at section 16

Answer (score 1):

From [this article](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/administer/security/user-group-ac-admin.html) :

```
The list of access rights applicable for the subject is constructed from:

    - the rights that you assign directly to the user account
    - plus all rights assigned to any of the groups that the user belongs to
```

Means that, Jackrabbit take group privilege instead of user's privilege. You can read the entire article, it is good for JackRabbit secutiry.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It was very helpful. but, based on it, I would say that user takes precedence:

Order of Precedence
Access rights in CRX are evaluated as follows:
  -  User principals always take precedence over group principals irrespective of:
        their order in the access control list
        their position in the node hierarchy